# Android sipmanger is depreciated , did Android native sip service stopped?

Tags: java, android, sip

I have notice that android sipmanager service is depreciated from android 32. Do they have any upgraded classes to support sip or they gave up this service to third party sip services like PJSIP ? Any suggestion and help would be highly appreciated as i have implement android native sip manger in some of my project and i am already regrating now ...[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Google is preparing to SIP support from the standard Android platfrom.

> [...]
>
> Based on these commits, it seems that Google is getting ready to remove SIP calling support from Android’s telephony service entirely. Once the SIP service is removed from the framework, apps relying on Android’s native SIP stack may break. [...]
>
> **In any case, it’s clear that Google no longer considers SIP support a worthwhile feature to maintain in Android. The SIP stack hasn’t been updated in years, so it was pretty much abandoned already — these code changes just make it official.**

Source: [Android 12 prepares to kill off native support for Internet-based SIP calling](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-12-killing-native-sip-calling/)

In short, SIP support hasn't been dropped *yet*, but you should be transitioning to a 3rd-party library to provide SIP support.  (If you want your apps to work on future Android versions.)